# Apache 2 The requested URL / was not found on this server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

I'm hosting a couple of webservers.  I've set the first one up with no problems.  On the second server when I attempt to navigate to it (http://192.168.1.47:99/) I get this error "The requested URL / was not found on this server."  I know that the port is being forwarded properly because I can access "http://192.168.1.47:99/phpmyadmin" just fine.  I've tried to figure this out for a week or so now and I'm at a loss.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Ubuntu Linux 10.04
Apache2
php5

I'll provide any additional information that may be needed.
Thanks!

Update - Included config files
    * [apache2.conf](http://pastebin.com/GG0VHDzx)
    * [httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/DJXdUQV6)
    * [ports.conf](http://pastebin.com/g1jMjrfy)
    * [sites enabled](http://pastebin.com/EFm95AzL)

Comment: Please post your config-file. I think u forgot to setup a proper index-file or just the host is not configured well.

Comment: I hope you meant the apache2 config file :-)  I appended it above.

Comment: Sure - any other config file should not deal with apache I hope! Unfortunatly, I can't see your appended file up to now.

Comment: Yeah, there were formatting errors it made me fix.  You should be able to see it now.

Comment: Additionally I need the following files: /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and /etc/apache2/ports.conf and the files in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/

Comment: Sure thing, give me just a few minutes.

I'm just going to link to all 4 files instead of pasting them here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand you, you want your server to respond on Port 99. Your configuration is listening on Port 80 instead. Change the following line in sites-enabled:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:99>
```

and in ports.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

to

```
NameVirtualHost *:99
```

Restart your apache. That should do it.

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that :-|  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 9):

we need to change the following lines to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
Note :- **Change here AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All usingsudo property**

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

 Now :- Restart your web server
**sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart**

It will work now..

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. You made my day

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it work without changing port you can follow these steps

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and add following line at end

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

then restart apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Better explain here
https://askubuntu.com/questions/55280/phpmyadmin-is-not-working-after-i-installed-it